# iPhone Fetch Request with localized sorting

Tags: iphone, core-data, localization, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I'm trying to get sorted localized data from a core data model. My code:

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName: entityDescriptionValue
                                                     inManagedObjectContext: context];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity: entityDescription];

[fetchRequest setPredicate: predicate];

NSSortDescriptor *sortBy = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"name" ascending: YES selector: @selector(localizedCompare:)];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortBy]];
[sortBy release];
```

But, when I get the objects, they still come sorted with the original values (non-localized  data).

What am I not doing right?

Comment: Can you give two examples of values for `name` that do not compare/sort correctly?

Comment: Are you sure the data sorts differently based on locale in all cases? It might sorting correctly.

Comment: For example, for country names: "England, France, Germany". When I set the language to portuguese, I'm getting the same order: "Inglaterra, França, Alemanha". The same as if I didn't use the localizedCompare: selector to sort the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you get the localized `names` from the CoreData entity? It's not that `localizedCompare:` magically retrieves the localized version of strings and compare them. Instead, it uses the localized sort orders to the same strings. 
The sorted version of an array containing `@"England"`, `@"France"`, `@"Germany"` would be the same in any country... they don't contain any accented characters or whatever. The result of `localizedCompare:` can only change when two languages use different sort order among letters.

If you want to retrieve something from `Localizable.strings` based on the property of the CoreData entities, you need to do that manually. Sqlite backend of CoreData won't handle that at the level of fetch requests. So you need to first fetch the entries in an `NSArray`, and then need to sort them using `sortedArrayUsing...:` by passing a method which retrieves the localized names by `NSLocalizedString` and compares them.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I had already done that, but I thought that Core Data would do that for me somehow.

Anyway, problem solved, thanks.